# Python - can i recall a list name from raw_input?

Tags: python-2.7, list, class, raw-input

I'm trying to create a game using python, but in my 'class Character:', i would like to do something like:

```
answer = raw_input('Which class do you want to play')
if answer = list_name[0]
self.stats = list_name
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First note that your `if` statement should have an `==` instead of `=`

Also this type of situation is a great time to use python's `in` statement which will check if a value matches any of the items in your list! You could try something like this:

```
list_name = ['classA','classB','classC','classD']

answer = raw_input('Which class do you want to play: ')

#Check if the answer is one of the options in your list
if answer in list_name:
    my_stats = answer
    print 'great, your class is '+my_stats

else:
    print 'sorry, ['+answer+'] is not an ok class'
```

Comment: Let's say my code is:
    Warrior_Stats = ['Warrior', 'HP']
    Hunter_Stats = ['Hunter', 'HP']
If i want my raw_input to be either Warrior or Hunter, how do i check every list and then return the list name^

Comment: @WilliamNi This answers your question, you should accept it as the answer

Comment: @WilliamNi I'm not sure I fully understand. I might be able to better help if you edit your question to add some code or pseudo code for what you're trying to do